# How can i add an existing docker repository to nexus

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

I have an external docker registry and i want to use nexus to analyze my repo for vulnerabilities but i don't know how to do it. For example, my repo is located at my.repo.location and i have a login user/password to access it. Is it even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first login to your nexus `docker login my.repo.location -U myLogin`

Then tag your image `docker tag image:tag my.repo.location/image:tag`

Then push the newly tagged image `docker push my.repo.location/image:tag`